# Use Ruby's << concatenation operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, operators, concatenation

Ruby has the `<<` concatenation operator. It can be used to push an item to an array (`.push()` can also be used in Ruby, but it is longer). It is used like this:

```
array = [1, 2]
array << 3
return array    # Will return [1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a similar Javascript operator to do that, or do I have to use `.push()`?

---

**Solved:** There is no Javascript operator similar to `<<`. You have to use push (Or create a function with a short name like `a` and push the only argument it takes)

---

Comment: If you want to use Ruby to write JavaScript, I'd suggest you have a look at Opal: https://github.com/opal/opal

Comment: I was not looking to use Ruby to write Javascript, only if Javascript has as a similar operator to `<<`. Thanks for the link anyway!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript does not support operator overloading and it is language with syntax characteristics quite different from Ruby.

For instance, in Ruby, you can omit parenthesis around parameters while making a function call.

```
arr << 4
```

is equivalent to

```
arr.<<(4)
```

JavaScript does not allow such flexibility, and hence, what you are asking may not be possible

Comment: So there is no Javascript operator? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is the shortest way I can think of that doesn't use push()

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
arr[arr.length] = 4;
```

It's also open to being wrong if the length property of arr has been externally manipulated.

```
arr.length = 100;
```

For instance. I like the best way would be to use push() but this is an alternative if you'd really like to use it. I'm not sure that a shorter way to push to arrays exists in JS.

Comment: This is longer than `arr.push(4)`

Comment: You misunderstood my question, I don't mind using `.push()`, but `<<` is 5 digits shorter. I wanted to find out if a Javascript operator exists. But thanks for the answer anyway!

Comment: Yeah, I tried messing around with adding Array.prototype["<<"] = Array.prototype.push; just to see what might be posisble, but I couldn't get it working and adding things to the prorotype probably isn't a great idea anyway.